# Try to use large SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, excel, vba

I try to use white large SQL query like this:

```
insert into R7810TEST 
   (select 1111111 ,  111111 , 1111111 ,'ORG' ,R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA ,8990  ,'ID' ,R401.ZIHUI_M_RASHI , R401.M_POLISA  ,R440.M_SOCHEN , 201507 ,'ORG'  , R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA  ,'RTP' , 'CUR'  , '1', '*' ,0  ,10000.00  ,0.00 , 0.00 , 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 , 0.00,0.00, 0.00 , r430.hf_oved_tagmulim_45 ,r430.hf_mavid_tagmulim , r430.hf_mavid_pizuim_mukar ,  0.00, r430.hf_mavid_chelef, r430.hf_oved_shonot, r430.hf_mavid_shonot , r430.hf_oved_tagmulim_47 ,'MNG', 0.00 , 0.00 ,0.00 ,0.00 , '*' , to_date ('20150701', 'yyyymmdd'), R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA, r400.sug_polisa, to_date ('20150701', 'yyyymmdd'),'CHI', '12' , 0, 0 ,'0', to_date ('19000101', 'yyyymmdd')  
from r400 R400 ,r401 R401 ,r430 r430 ,r440 r440
where r400.m_polisa = r401.m_polisa
and r401.m_polisa = r430.m_polisa
and r430.m_polisa= r440.m_polisa
and r401.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) from r401 aa where aa.m_polisa = r401.m_polisa)
and r430.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) from r430 aa where aa.m_polisa = r430.m_polisa)
and r440.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) from r440 aa where aa.m_polisa = r440.m_polisa)
and r401.status_rashi = 10
--and r401.status_rashi in (30,35)
----and r401.status_rashi in (90)
--and r401.status_rashi = 20
and r400.sug_polisa in ('1','3','5','7')
and r400.sug_hishtatfut <>0
and r400.sug_hazmada <>0
and r400.m_polisa IN (XXXXX));
```

And I get an exception from SQL, I use Oracle and vba via Excel, I think this too large string so it's not work and the sql get part of query. What can I do with how can I use this query in vba code?

Comment: You need to tell us what error you're getting. This query is far from too big.

Comment: Remove the parentheses, `insert into R7810TEST select ...`.

Comment: : Description : "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" : String : but if i wath on the qurey so not all the qurey inside the strinfg and thi the rison the sql think has missing right parenthesis

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's difficult to understand. E.g. the signs '.', '!', '?' are not only looking good. They are improving the readability and understandability massively. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some possible things at play here.  It's hard to tell without the DDL for `R7810TEST`, but I have 2.5 guesses

1. The last statement in your SQL says `r400.m_polisa IN (XXXXX)`.  This does not appear to be strongly typed.  Was this a placeholder, or is this the real SQL?  If XXXXX is a string, you need quotes.  If it's supposed to be a number, well...  you know.  If it's a field in one of the tables, then I suppose it's okay, but it's a weird construct if that's the case.
2. VBA doesn't do well with large concatenations.  You didn't list your VBA code, but I can easily see it puking on a string as large as yours.  To get around this, you can break the concatenation up into multiple steps.  While your SQL actually appears to have balanced parentheses (with the exception of the fact that the parentheses around the select statement are unnecessary), when you are trying to wrap this in VBA strings, it's not difficult to miss something small.
3. A follow-up on item 2 -- again with VBA concatenation, something as simple as a missing space can derail your best SQL.  For example:

For example:

```
sql = "select one, two, three" & _
      "from foo"
```

Unintentionally becomes:

```
select one, two, threefrom foo
```

Sample for point #2:

```
cmd.CommandText = _
    "insert into R7810TEST" & _
    "select" & _
    "   1111111 ,  111111 , 1111111 ,'ORG' ,R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA ,8990  ,'ID' ," & _
    "   R401.ZIHUI_M_RASHI , R401.M_POLISA  ,R440.M_SOCHEN , 201507 ,'ORG'  ," & _
    "   R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA  ,'RTP' , 'CUR'  , '1', '*' ,0  ,10000.00  ," & _
    "   0.00 , 0.00 , 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 , 0.00,0.00, 0.00 ," & _
    "   r430.hf_oved_tagmulim_45 ,r430.hf_mavid_tagmulim ," & _
    "   r430.hf_mavid_pizuim_mukar ,  0.00, r430.hf_mavid_chelef," & _
    "   r430.hf_oved_shonot, r430.hf_mavid_shonot , r430.hf_oved_tagmulim_47 ," & _
    "   'MNG', 0.00 , 0.00 ,0.00 ,0.00 , '*' , to_date ('20150701', 'yyyymmdd')," & _
    "   R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA, r400.sug_polisa, to_date ('20150701', 'yyyymmdd')," & _
    "   'CHI', '12' , 0, 0 ,'0', to_date ('19000101', 'yyyymmdd') "

 cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText & _
    "from r400 R400 ,r401 R401 ,r430 r430 ,r440 r440 " & _
    "where r400.m_polisa = r401.m_polisa " & _
    "and r401.m_polisa = r430.m_polisa " & _
    "and r430.m_polisa= r440.m_polisa " & _
    "and r401.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) " & _
         "from r401 aa where aa.m_polisa = r401.m_polisa) " & _
    "and r430.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) " & _
         "from r430 aa where aa.m_polisa = r430.m_polisa) " & _
    "and r440.tr_rishum in (select max(aa.tr_rishum) " & _
         "from r440 aa where aa.m_polisa = r440.m_polisa) " & _
    "and r401.status_rashi = 10 " & _
    "and r400.sug_polisa in ('1','3','5','7') " & _
    "and r400.sug_hishtatfut <>0 " & _
    "and r400.sug_hazmada <>0 " & _
    "and r400.m_polisa IN ('XXXXX')"
```

When in doubt, make liberal use of whitespace in your SQL.

Parting shot -- if this doesn't help, please post the DDL for your tables.  It may provide a hint as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the error is, but it looks like your insert...select is malformed. As a matter of good practice, you should specify the columns you are inserting into before your select clause, and remove the parentheses around the select. Something like this:

```
insert into R7810TEST
( column1, column2, ...etc)
select 1111111 ,  111111 , 1111111 ,'ORG' ...etc
```

Comment: i i run this query just like this in PL/SQL is runnig excellent when i put it in vba i not working, so the qurey is good

Comment: "ORA-00936: missing expression" this is the error i get an this is the string after i insert to string virble: "insert into R7810TEST
(select 7349926.89865094 ,  580081.084408164, 6215666.96627682,'ORG',R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA,8990,'ID',
R401.ZIHUI_M_RASHI, 775932 ,R440.M_SOCHEN,1 ,'ORG', R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA,'RTP',
, '1', '*',
8 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,
1 ,1 ,
1,1 ,1 ,  NOT ALL THE STRING GET IN TO THE STRING VAR

Comment: " R401.ZIHUI_BAAL_POLISA,'RTP', , '1'," will give you an error, as there is nothing between two of those commas. It looks like there is a bug in the code you are using to construct this query.